# Custom Sign In Page has an SPContext.Current that is always null

Tags: 2013, development, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, spcontext

> **Found the Solution**
>
> The solution was to add a Root Site Collection (as the code was running in a sub-site, without a root site).
>
> See [This Solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/100475/24941)

---

> **Important Update** (*based on feedback received so far*)
>
> I do not have Visual Studio installed on the SharePoint 2013 Server. All code is compiled in Visual Studio 2012 remotely using references to the required SharePoint 2013 DLLs and digitally signed so it can be deployed into the Global Assembly Cache on the SharePoint 2013 Server.
>
> At the most basic level this statement fails at point of `Page_Load()`;
>
> ```cs
> SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.GetIisSettingsWithFallback(
>   SPContext.Current.Site.Zone
> );
> ```
>
> Because `SPContext.Current` is **always** `null`.

## Background

Client needs there SharePoint site to be accessible using Form Based Authentication for external users and Windows Authentication for internal users (corporate). Have gone through and have setup both Authentication Providers and now get the default sign in.

[image: Sign In]

Although everything works Windows Authentication still displays the Provider selection screen when the client wants the Windows Authentication to just automatically pass through and display a Forms Based Authentication login screen if that fails.

Been struggling with this for days after looking at various blogs and articles I feel I'm no further along and that is depressing. At the moment I can't workout whether I'm missing something really fundamental.

## Custom Sign In Page

The page is based off an amalgamation of;

1. `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Template\IdentityModel\Login\default.aspx`
2. `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Template\IdentityModel\Forms\default.aspx`

This is just a first attempt and realise I won't need all these controls eventually, just wanted to see how things hang together.

```html
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharepointIdentity" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="MyCustomSignInModule.SignInForm, MyCustomSignInModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f2ae721af94bf9e9" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/15/errorv15.master"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
  <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server"  EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode" Id="ClaimsLogonPageTitleInTitleArea" />
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
  <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server"  EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode" Id="ClaimsFormsPageTitle" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
  <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server"  EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode" Id="ClaimsLogonPageMessage" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <SharepointIdentity:LogonSelector ID="ClaimsLogonSelector" runat="server" />

 <div id="SslWarning" style="color:red;display:none">
 <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server"  EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode" Id="ClaimsFormsPageMessage" />
 </div>
  <script language="javascript" >
    if (document.location.protocol != 'https:') {
      var SslWarning = document.getElementById('SslWarning');
      SslWarning.style.display = '';
    }
  </script>
 <asp:login id="signInControl" FailureText="<%$Resources:wss,login_pageFailureText%>" runat="server" width="100%">
  <layouttemplate>
    <asp:label id="FailureText" class="ms-error" runat="server"/>
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td nowrap="nowrap"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,login_pageUserName%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/></td>
      <td width="100%"><asp:textbox id="UserName" autocomplete="off" runat="server" class="ms-inputuserfield" width="99%" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td nowrap="nowrap"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,login_pagePassword%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/></td>
      <td width="100%"><asp:textbox id="password" TextMode="Password" autocomplete="off" runat="server" class="ms-inputuserfield" width="99%"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right"><asp:button id="login" commandname="Login" text="<%$Resources:wss,login_pagetitle%>" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><asp:checkbox id="RememberMe" text="<%$SPHtmlEncodedResources:wss,login_pageRememberMe%>" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </layouttemplate>
 </asp:login>
 <asp:label id="DebugText" class="ms-error" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

## MyCustomSignInModule Assembly

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace MyCustomSignInModule
{
    public class SignInForm : FormsSignInPage
    {
        protected Label DebugText;

        private static SPIisSettings _iisSettings;

        internal static SPIisSettings iisSettings
        {
            get
            {
                if (_iisSettings == null)
                {
                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        _iisSettings = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.GetIisSettingsWithFallback(SPContext.Current.Site.Zone);
                    });
                }
                return _iisSettings;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            bool isWindowsAuth = false;
            string username = request["username"];
            string password = request["password"];


            // If no username is provided, it'll probably be Windows Authentication (NTLMv2 protocol)
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                isWindowsAuth = true;
            }

            try
            {

                //SPIisSettings iisSettings = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.IisSettings[SPUrlZone.Default];

                if (isWindowsAuth)
                {
                    // Windows Authentication it is

                    if (iisSettings.UseWindowsClaimsAuthenticationProvider)
                    {
                        SPAuthenticationProvider provider = iisSettings.WindowsClaimsAuthenticationProvider;
                        RedirectToLoginPage(provider); // This should cause automatic sign in
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // FBA authentication it is.

                    SPFormsAuthenticationProvider formsClaimsAuthenticationProvider = iisSettings.FormsClaimsAuthenticationProvider;

                    SecurityToken token = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url), formsClaimsAuthenticationProvider.MembershipProvider, formsClaimsAuthenticationProvider.RoleProvider, username, password, SPFormsAuthenticationOption.PersistentSignInRequest);

                    if (null != token)
                    {
                        EstablishSessionWithToken(token);
                        base.RedirectToSuccessUrl();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DebugText.Text = ex.ToString();
            }

        }

        // Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.LogonSelector
        private void RedirectToLoginPage(SPAuthenticationProvider provider)
        {
            string components = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Query, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);
            string url = provider.AuthenticationRedirectionUrl.ToString();
            if (provider is SPWindowsAuthenticationProvider)
            {
                components = EnsureUrlSkipsFormsAuthModuleRedirection(components, true);
            }
            SPUtility.Redirect(url, SPRedirectFlags.Default, this.Context, components);
        }

        // Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility
        private string EnsureUrlSkipsFormsAuthModuleRedirection
            (string url, bool urlIsQueryStringOnly)
        {
            if (!url.Contains("ReturnUrl="))
            {
                if (urlIsQueryStringOnly)
                {
                    url = url + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) ? "" : "&");
                }
                else
                {
                    url = url + ((url.IndexOf('?') == -1) ? "?" : "&");
                }
                url = url + "ReturnUrl=";
            }
            return url;
        }

        // Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.IdentityModelSignInPageBase
        private void EstablishSessionWithToken(SecurityToken securityToken)
        {
            if (securityToken == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("securityToken");
            }
            SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam = SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current;
            if (fam == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            fam.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(securityToken);
        }

        private SPAuthenticationProvider
                GetAuthenticationProvider(string providerName)
        {
            SPIisSettings iisSettings =
                SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.IisSettings[SPUrlZone.Default];

            foreach (SPAuthenticationProvider currentProvider in
                        iisSettings.ClaimsAuthenticationProviders)
            {
                if (currentProvider.DisplayName.ToLower() ==
                            providerName.ToLower())
                {
                    return currentProvider;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

## The Process

I have a test Sharepoint instance running on the VM but no Visual Studio installed as all the development is done remotely. The current process I follow;

1. Build C# Class Library (this will be `MyCustomSignInModule.Dll`)
2. Sign `MyCustomSignInModule.Dll` so it can be placed in the VM GAC.
3. Register `MyCustomSignInModule.Dll` in the GAC on the VM instance.
4. Save `SignInForm.aspx` into the `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\` which is the equivalent of `<SharePointSiteRoot>/_layouts/` virtual directory in IIS.
5. In SharePoint Central Administration site set the Custom Sign In Page to my page `~/_layouts/SignInForm.aspx`.
6. Reset IIS using `iisreset`.
7. Test accessing SharePoint site (this is where it falls over).

### The Problem

[image: Sign In Error]

If it's not that clear the error is;

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at
MyCustomSignInModule.SignInForm.b__0() at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3() at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param) at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) at MyCustomSignInModule.SignInForm.get_iisSettings() at 
MyCustomSignInModule.SignInForm.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

### SPContext.Current is null why?

The `NullReferenceException` is being caused by `SPContext.Current` being null, but I can't workout why it's null and no amount of articles I've looked at have so far led to helping me solve this. I'm hoping by posting my whole process here someone might be able to point me to what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50429/claims-authentication-adfs-sts

Comment: @Nikhil Your solution still references `SPContext.Current` which I've explained in the question is always null, until I can get to the bottom of why it's null I can't implement anyone elses solution.

Comment: if you are using sharepoint 2013, why you are saving your SignInForm.aspx in 14 folder?

Comment: @Ashish Good question but that is how the `/_layouts/` folder is mapped in IIS it points to `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`. There is a nested Virtual Directory `/_layouts/15/` that points to `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`. I have tried putting my `SignInForm.aspx` in this folder but I get the same result.

Comment: I'm intrigued @Nikhil you spent the time commenting but didn't feel my question deserved an upvote, how am I going to get the visibility I feel it deserves if people don't upvote it. Is it not clear? not detailed enough? Tell me what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Lankymart where did you take the code for the custom signin module from? I'm pretty sure SPContext.Current is null because you are getting it within the RunWithElevatedPrivileges code block

Comment: @MdMazzotti The `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` was added after reading various articles that suggested the reason the `SPContext.Current` is null because the code didn't have permission to execute it. I originally started off with [this 2010 example](http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2011/06/23/sharepoint-2010-custom-login-page/) but even that gives me a null reference which forced me to look into why. [Another article I used](http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2012/06/11/custom-sign-in-and-sign-out-page/) which is closest to my required implementation (Forms and Windows Auth passthrough).

Comment: @Lankymart mmm, I spotted something. Can you try removing the static modifier from the iisSettings property (so that it reads internal SPIisSettings iisSettings) ? (and from the _iisSetting field as well)

Comment: Appreciate your comments @MdMazzotti. May be I should have provided less code though, you see if I had a `Page_Load()` with nothing but `SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.GetIisSettingsWithFallback(SPContext.Current.Site.Zone);` it would still fails because at the time of load the `SPContext.Current` is null regardless of how I reference it.

Comment: @Lankymart and what about HttpContext.Current? Can you test if it is null as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13923/discussion-between-mdmazzotti-and-lankymart)

Comment: @Lankymart I took the time to test your code on my environment and it's working just fine. There must be something related to how you are deploying the solution (I don't understand how you can even develop on a machine without SP2013 installed)

Comment: @MdMazzotti That's interesting because that might be the issue the DLL isn't trusted by SharePoint or something. I explained my process in the question basically I create a Standard C# Class Library add the SharePoint references and use that as the base code for my ASP.net page using the `inherit` attribute.

Comment: @MdMazzotti When you say it worked in your environment what did you actually get?

Comment: @Lankymart I got logged in (with WindowsAuth). I stepped through the code, so I'm sure the page got called

Comment: @MdMazzotti What method did you use to deploy it?, I'm wondering if my problem is the process I'm using.

Comment: @Lankymart I deployed directly from Visual Studio. Tomorrow if I have some spare time I will try to deploy with your method and let you know

Comment: i upvoted , sorry about that .

Comment: @Nikhil Thanks, it wasn't a criticism just wondered if I could have explained my problem better.

Comment: @Lankymart here's a screenshot proving that SPContext.Current is not null (when deploying the solution from Visual Studio): http://s4.postimg.org/86ae7jwkt/loginpage.jpg

Comment: @Lankymart I just tested your deployment method (I built the DLL on a different machine whit no sharepoint installed, compiled and manually deployed). It is working fine. So I have no idea why it doesn't work on your environment. The code is correct

Comment: @Lankymart here's a screenshot proving that the custom signin page got called (I just commented out the RedirectToLoginPage(provider); line and added this  DebugText.Text = "You are about to be redirected using WindowsClaims auth provider";) http://postimg.org/image/ttp2cwcgj/

Comment: @MdMazzotti Weird so you don't get a NullReferenceException at all? Must be the way my installation is setup then or something really confused now, but thank you for your persistent help this is invaluable information.

Comment: @Lankymart yes, got no NullReferenceException at all. Weird indeed.

Comment: @MdMazzotti Could you describe your environment setup?, for example mine is: `Windows Server 2012 - 64 bit, SharePoint 2013 Foundation Server - Running on a VM`.

Comment: @Lankymart let's continue in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13923/discussion-between-mdmazzotti-and-lankymart

Comment: Do you have AAM enabled? If configured incorrectly then you will get this.

Comment: @HughWood That is an interesting point, I do and to be completely honest with you I tend not to mess with it and I've looked at some articles on the subject but still struggle to understand if it is configured right.

Comment: Then I suggest to add your AAM configuration to the post, see if this will bring the issue to light.

Comment: @HughWood After your suggestion about AAM did a little googling and found a few articles I'd already looked at but also some I hadn't including this one [Post by Latortue Jun 7, 2013 at 3:52 PM - SharePoint 2010 automatic sign-in with mixed authentication](http://spautomaticsignin.codeplex.com/discussions/438288) which looks very promising, you see my site is setup as a subsite and i'm not sure there is a site collection at the route which might explain this behaviour.

Comment: So you have made a managed path and a site collection under it, this is what is throwing the error. That kind of makes sense too. There are a lot of strange things can happen with AAM: http://appdevonsharepoint.com/common-alternate-access-mappings-issues/

Comment: Thanks @MdMazzotti, I can't believe it but it turned out to be a missing Root Site Collection causing the `SPContext` to be `Null`. Appreciate all your help, you went above and beyond. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of what was causing the issue, firstly would like to thank both [@MdMazzotti](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/8642/mdmazzotti) and [@Hugh Wood](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/9970/hugh-wood) for their persistent help.

In the end I stumbled on the fix which turned out to be partly because the way the site was built. In my particular case the site was built as a sub-site in SharePoint, for whatever reason this meant there was no Site Collection at the root of the SharePoint website which was the cause of the `Null` `SPContext` in my code.

After adding a Root Site Collection my code began to work as expected.

Comment: I'm glad to see you finally found out what the problem was

Comment: @MdMazzotti Can't believe how simple it was, just sorry I didn't provide the site structure. Maybe then would have gotten to the bottom of the issue far quicker. Really appreciate your help though, was invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here, but here are some things that I think could help.

Add this JavaScript code to the custom sign in page (before your if-statement):

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext');
```

You could also add this JavaScript to your page to test if it works or not, using the console:

```
var clientContext = new  SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
console.log(clientContext);
```

If it returns something, then we have progress! If not, then I'll have to continue my search, since I find your question interesting.

**EDIT**

Instead of using this server-side code:

```
if (_iisSettings == null)
{
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
      _iisSettings = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.GetIisSettingsWithFallback(SPContext.Current.Site.Zone);
   });
}
return _iisSettings;
```

Try using this instead:

```
if (_iisSettings == null)
{
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
      _iisSettings = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.GetIisSettingsWithFallback(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Site.Zone);
   });
}
return _iisSettings;
```

I searched around and noticed that in some of the code examples I encountered, the _iisSettings was different from yours. Perhaps that is why your SPContext.Current is null?

Comment: Isn't the code above server side code, not javascript?

Comment: Yeah it's [tag:c#], I didn't know if this question was a good fit for this site. Do you mean add the javascript in the `ASPX` page above the `if (document.location.protocol != 'https:') {` line?

Comment: Ah, it is indeed. Let my edit my answer.

Comment: Yes I did mean to add it in the ASPX page above that if-statement, sorry if I wasn't too clear. I sometimes forget to mention things. :)

Comment: The `Microsoft.SharePoint.` part is a namespace which I declare at the top of the class `using Microsoft.SharePoint;` so those two examples are equivalent, but appreciate your efforts nonetheless.

Comment: I see. Sorry about that, I thought it might have made a difference. I'm not that good at C# yet but I'm starting to get the hang of it. I just got another question: if you deploy your code, could you put some breaks near the piece of code I mentioned? And see if there is any value assigned to _iisSettings? If there isn't, then at least we know it has something to do with that piece of code. And if not, use break on other lines that might be the cause. It might be helpful.

Comment: That's part of the problem with my process I compile the DLL in Visual Studio as a Standard C# Class Library with the SharePoint required references in and sign it so it can be added to the GAC on the SharePoint 2013 Server. The deployment is entirely manual which means I can't step through it and my attempts to write to the trace log etc have been fruitless.

Comment: In that case, you could use Console.WriteLine() in your code to log things to the console of your browser. Place it wherever you'd like to check if values are assigned or not, and put for example _iisSettings in there to see if it gives null.

Comment: Just used console to see what `SP` is set to and it returns `Object {__namespace: true, SOD: Object, UI: Object}` if I try `SP.ClientContext` it returns undefined.

Comment: And what if you use the console for SPContext.Current or SPContext? Do those return anything?

Comment: @Magali I'm confused. Are you referring to C# or javascript?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! I was referring to C#, if you use the JavaScript console for the SP.ClientContext then it will return as undefined because you didn't load it anywhere on the page. But the SPContext should be server-side, and if you use the console in C# to check that then it should return something.

Comment: @Magali the poster is developing on a remote machine and manually deploying to the server. I don't see how your suggestion applies in his case...

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081251/how-can-this-throw-a-nullreferenceexception

SPContext.Current doesn't work under Elevated Privileges, so you have to rewrite like in the answer above.

Comment: Elevated Privileges was a workaround, even without it it still doesn't work for me. @MdMazzotti has already commented that he has deployed the code successfully and it works so it looks like it might be my method of remotely compiling the assembly and deploying it to the SharePoint Server manually.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this MSDN article: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms468609(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms468609%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

I think because you use a C# Class Library project in Visual studio, you are not in a web context and can't use SPContext.Current as explained in the MSDN article above.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts but I have read that article previously and @MdMazzotti has proved that the code can be remotely compiled to a DLL and still work (see [latest comments](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95952/custom-sign-in-page-has-an-spcontext-current-that-is-always-null/96860?noredirect=1#comment95634_95952) in the question).

Comment: The page inherits from the class declared inside the .DLL, so the fact that the DLL was compiled from a Class Library project doesn't really have any influence. As long as the DLL has been properly deployed to the GAC, where and how it was compiled is irrelevant

Comment: Plerse edit your first answer instead of posting multiple ones!